# Can the coordinates of a tikz node surrounded by a rectangle be perscribed?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the word "foo" enclosed in a red box. I would like the "NorthWest" corner of the box to be located at the location `(0, 0)`. My code locates the center of the box at `(0, 0)`. Can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \node[draw=red] (foo) at (O) {foo};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More generally, can any one of the four vertices of this rectangle be positioned at a point `(x0, y0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `anchor` setting is for, e.g.

```
\node [anchor=north west, draw=red] at (0,0) {foo};
```

To see what the available anchor names are, look at the node shape in question in chapter 72 *Shape library* in the TikZ manual. Each shape has a figure similar to this one, for the standard rectangle shape:

[image]

Comment: Oh, wow yes. Thank you!